# Failing to get picture in fragment while requesting permission for first time?

Tags: android, permissions, android-camera, onactivityresult

Hi I have an `MainActivity` inside which I have a `MyFragment`, I ruqest a runtime permission from `MyFragmnet`, once I get the permission in `onRequestPermissionsResult` I am making call to `MyFragment.this.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, profileimageRequest);`, when I am requesting permission for first time it fails to show the picture, but when I run the take picture code for second time it has permission already (Permission granted on first run) here I am getting image properly.

I have enabled logs at every place i.e. `onActivityResult()` of `MainActivity` as well as `MyFragmnet`,  flow stays the same but results vary, when there is permission granted in advance it successfully shows the picture, but for the first time permission even after granting it fails to show the picture taken.

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
MyFragment.this.requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                                    MainActivity.PROFILEIMAGE_REQUEST);
                    }
                });
```

Below is code for permission result callback

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.e(getTag(),"onRequestPermissionsResult");
        System.out.println();
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MainActivity.PROFILEIMAGE_REQUEST: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.e(getTag(),"Inside if------onRequestPermissionsResult");
                    System.out.println();
                    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(mainActivity.getPackageManager()) != null) {
if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    MyFragment.this.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, profileimageRequest);
}
                }
                }
            }
........
        }
    }
```

Code to set the picture :

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       Log.e(getTag(),"onActivityResult "+requestCode);
//        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,requestCode,data);
        if (requestCode == MainActivity.PROFILEIMAGE_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Log.e(getTag(),"ok ");
                handleProfileImage();
            }
        }
```

All above code is in fragment `onActivityResult` of `MainActivity` is also implemented with super callback.

Also I am trying to figure out whats going on using debugger but debugger gets disconncted once take picture intent is fired as well as it gets disconnected when the permission box shows up.

Comment: once you get the permission you need to start the workflow again

Comment: @dex please see the edited question

Comment: this "AccountFragment.this. startActivityForResult(..)" should be replaced with getActivity(). startActivityForResult(...)

Comment: @dex already did that, the problem is with permission.